# Serialize unknown object to xml

Tags: xml, generics, object, serialization

I have an object which I am hoping to send via a WCF service, this needs to be able to serialize and object which I may not know the type of. I see that this works with primative types, however with reference types I am unable to successfully serialize the values. In the below test I receive an error message whilst debugging when it tries to serialize either the List or Tuple objects. Is there a good way to perform this process without knowing the type?

```
[DataContract]
public class SizingObject
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<SizingItem> SizingItems { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SizingItem
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ListItemId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public object Item { get; set; }
}
```

```
        var i = new SizingObject();
        i.SizingItems = new List<SizingItem>();
        i.SizingItems.Add(new SizingItem
                              {
                                  Item = "String",
                                  ListItemId = string.Empty,
                                  Name = "string item",
                                  Unit = string.Empty,
                                  Value = string.Empty
                              });

        i.SizingItems.Add(new SizingItem
                              {
                                  Item = 0.23,
                                  ListItemId = string.Empty,
                                  Name = "double item",
                                  Unit = string.Empty,
                                  Value = string.Empty
                              });

        i.SizingItems.Add(new SizingItem
                              {
                                  Item = new List<double> { 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                                  ListItemId = string.Empty,
                                  Name = "list<double> item",
                                  Unit = string.Empty,
                                  Value = string.Empty
                              });

        i.SizingItems.Add(new SizingItem
                              {
                                  Item = new Tuple<string, double>("TupleItem", 2.00),
                                  ListItemId = string.Empty,
                                  Name = "Tuple<string, double> item",
                                  Unit = string.Empty,
                                  Value = string.Empty
                              });

        // Serialize User Data
        var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SizingObject));
        serializer1.Serialize(stringWriter, i);
        var xml = stringWriter.ToString();

        var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SizingObject));
        i = (SizingObject)serializer2.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));

        var dict = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>();
        dict.Add(typeof(string), e => e as string);
        dict.Add(typeof(double), e => e);
        dict.Add(typeof(List<double>), e => e as List<double>);
        dict.Add(typeof(Tuple<string, double>), e => e as Tuple<string, double>);

        foreach (var item in i.SizingItems)
        {
            var result = dict[item.Item.GetType()].Invoke(item.Item);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was able to resolve this issue when I spent a little more time with it and by supplying a set of known types. I wasn't able to serialize the Tuple type so had to create an alternative but this was as I had expected given its type, lists and other objects are now fully serializable however.

`var types = new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(double), typeof(List), typeof(WCFTuple) };`

```
            // Serialize User Data
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SizingObject), types);
            serializer1.Serialize(stringWriter, i);
            var xml = stringWriter.ToString();

            // Deserialize object.
            var serializer2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SizingObject), types);
            i = (SizingObject)serializer2.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ever thought of simply sending it as an `Object`?

Assuming you have a copy of the class "template" on both ends, you could send it as an Object and then cast it on the receiving end to the type.

Another idea is to transmit it as XML, assuming there are no real sensative pieces of information, and rebuild the class on the receiving end.

Comment: That was what I was aiming for. My concern was that the serialization of the object type would fail due to the object types being unknown. When I run the above code I can create a list<object> and populated it successfully, as well as retrieve the values back out at the other end. However the serialization doesn't appear to work. Should I not be concerned about this with WCF?

Comment: Tell you the truth i have not had much success with Serialization, of course clients arent willing to spend the time for me to get it working properly, so i usually have the information sent to a WebService as XML and let the service do the transitioning.  Most of its the prefab WebService class structures from VS, but works.  Although clunky due to bloated class builds but works.